# Classification of True and False according to whether special characters are used at Python

Tags: python, classification, special-characters

Question)

```
a = '[ 4916760:L] 71001 201 335 2 23593634 727151802) (50 107724 14253 
19/144 20/139'
b = '[ 4916770:L] 71001 202 336 3 7 2 107726 13457 19/145 20/132'
```

If special characters ('(',')') include in a string, return false value.

Answer)
a -> False
b -> True

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `not any(...)`:

```
>>> not any(i in a for i in ('(', ')'))
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '[ 4916760:L] 71001 201 335 2 23593634 727151802) (50 107724 14253 19/144 20/139'
b = '[ 4916770:L] 71001 202 336 3 7 2 107726 13457 19/145 20/132'

def in_str(a):
    result = ('(' or ')') not in a
    return result

result_a = in_str(a)
print(result_a)

result_b = in_str(b)
print(result_b)

out:
   False
   True
```